# LINQ query cannot evaluate GET parameter in StartsWith

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make a query through a GET request (in Angular.js) using .NET Web API and Entity Framework using LINQ and MySQL db.

```
http://localhost/ProductsApp/api/clientes/GetByName/M
```

The problems is that the parameter passed by GET is not evaluated and I don't get any results (even though `name` is being set correctly to `"M"` according to the debugger).
However, if I hardcode a string, I get the expected result.

```
    [ActionName("GetByName")]
    public IEnumerable<cliente> GetByName(string name)
    {

        var query = from c in context.clientes where c.nome.StartsWith(name) select c;
        var query2 = from c in context.clientes where c.nome.StartsWith("M") select c;
        var query3 = context.clientes.Where(c => c.nome.StartsWith(name));
        var query4 = context.clientes.Where(c => c.nome.StartsWith("M"));

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

My WebApiConfig.cs has the following lines:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
    defaults: null
);
```

I suppose that LINQ resolves the variables when it is executed, as hinted below (I removed the unimportant part of the query):

```
query.ToString()
"SELECT [...] WHERE `Extent1`.`nome` LIKE 'p__linq__0%'"
query2.ToString()
"SELECT [...] WHERE `Extent1`.`nome` LIKE 'M%'"
query3.ToString()
"SELECT [...] WHERE `Extent1`.`nome` LIKE 'p__linq__0%'"
query4.ToString()
"SELECT [...] WHERE `Extent1`.`nome` LIKE 'M%'"
```

Both `query2` and `query4` return correct values while `query` and `query3` do not. Why? How can I make it work?

Comment: `even though name is being set correctly to "M"` You seem to have some pretty compelling evidence that that isn't the case.  How do you know that `name` *is* being set to `M`?

Comment: @Servy because the debugger tells me so. Could it be mistaken?

Comment: @user2753837 can you please supply the fill query generated by query.ToString(). "LIKE 'p__linq__0%'" does not look correct. it should be something like "LIKE `@p__linq__0 + '%'". It looks like Entity framework is not creating a proper parameter. that is why you are getting noting back

Comment: @Ockert `"SELECT\r\n`Extent1`.`cliente_id`, \r\n`Extent1`.`nome`, \r\n`Extent1`.`email`, \r\n`Extent1`.`endereco`\r\nFROM `cliente` AS `Extent1`\r\n WHERE `Extent1`.`nome` LIKE 'p__linq__0%'"`

Comment: @user2753837 It is definitely a problem with the way EF builds up the query. I don't know if this will work. can you try var query = context.clientes.Where(c => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%" + name, c.nome) > 0); You need to add the namespace System.Data.Objects.SqlClient

Comment: "ExceptionMessage":"The specified method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] PatIndex(System.String, System.String)' on the type 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.","ExceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException"

Comment: Do you know what might be causing that problem with Entity?

Comment: What version of EF are you using? I've done something similar with EF 6 and the query generated is not the same as yours.

Comment: You are correct. I also found this. Check my answer. I'm using version 6.9.5. I updated and it's working correctly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reported bug with MySQL Entity Framework 6.9.5

Bug #74918 : Incorrect query result with Entity Framework 6:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74918

It has been fixed in MySQL Connector/Net 6.7.7 / 6.8.5 / 6.9.6 releases.

Changelog:
With Entity Framework 6, passing in a string reference to the "StartWith"
clause would return incorrect results.

Alternatively, a workaround is to use `.Substring(0)` which forces Entity not to use `LIKE` (might affect performance).

```
var query = context.clientes.Where(c => c.nome.StartsWith(name.Substring(0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your name parameter does not equal to "M", it is possible that this value is null. WebApi probably expects a "id" parameter and not "name"

Add a route attribute to make sure that the correct value is passed to the name parameter

```
[Route("api/clientes/GetByName/{name}")]
public IEnumerable<cliente> GetByName(string name)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have said that my WebApiConfig.cs has the following lines
`config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByName",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
            defaults: null
            );`
The debugger tells me `name` is `"M"`

Comment: Do you have multiple Get methods with parameter

Comment: @DineshChauhan The only other get method with parameter is the default method that receives an id (.../api/clientes/id). When debugging, the correct method gets called

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one GET method with parameter so you have to change your WebApiConfig.cs

```
           config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

or another way to do this you have to hardcode your controller and action in WebApiConfig.cs like this

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "GetApi",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { action = "GetByName", controller = "Your Controller" });
```

Your Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<cliente> GetByName(string name)
{
}
```

Call it like this

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'localhost/ProductsApp/api/clientes/GetByName?Name='+ M,
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I updated the question with the config file. I also tried your possibilities and it still doesn't work